# javascript facebook like button is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

on my website I have a facebook like button (to like my facebook page). It has been working fine until today. when someone clicks the like button it like the page, then immediately switch to the previous mode of not liking the page. On my main page I am getting this error

```
There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and fixing any errors.
```

I tried to scan my page, but I have no errors nor warnings.
I also tried making a new like button here `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/`
but with every page I tried (even pages that are not mine) such as (`http://www.facebook.com/americanexpress`) I am still getting the same problem (you can see the problem on facebook without having to paste the code to your page).
did facebook change any code or something ?
do I need to change any code such as my java script ?

Comment: Right now I'm not getting error messages. Sometimes Facebook has javascript has errors so try cleaning cachè.

Comment: what do you mean by "cachè" ? and how do I clean it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ILoveItWhenGirlsLookAtTheirOwnBoobs" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

It is working correctly on my blog. You can check my blog here:

```
http://mostvisitedbloginasia.blogspot.com/
```

For your page, just change the username of your page. It looks like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/YOUR-USER-NAME" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

It will work correctly!